# Using Xcode without Administrator access?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have a 2008 late MacBook on which I have a standard account. I want to use Xcode but after clicking on Run it asks for an Administrator password which I don't have access to. So is there any way I can still use Xcode ? This happens for Terminal apps as well as iOS projects. It asks to run the Debugger tool.

Comment: Just give admin access to the devs. Why would you trust then to write code but not other things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So is there any way I can still use Xcode ?

Basically, you need to go find the administrator for the machine and ask them to allow debugging. The reason that Xcode is asking for the administrator password is that the debugger, by its very nature, needs to be able to take control of another process. That's potentially a dangerous thing to allow -- if you can debug another process, you can make it do all sorts of things.

An administrator should be able to grant you access to the debugger by adding you to the `_developer` group. They can use this command:

```
sudo dscl . append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership <username>
```

where `<username>` is, of course, your userid. That prevents you from having to get the admin to come type their password every time you want to start using the debugger.